# Wicket : CheckBoxMultipleChoice is not saving values in model object

Tags: java, apache, wicket, wicket-1.5

My code looks like this

html

> < div wicket:id="metroEthernetChildchkLeft">

java code

initializing CheckBoxMultipleChoice  in constructor and then later setting the values of list and model using setter methods

```
class <some name>

   private CheckBoxMultipleChoice<String> metroEthernetChildchkLeft;

   <constructor>()
    {    metroEthernetChildchkLeft = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<String>("metroEthernetChildchkLeft");
         metroEthernetChildchkLeft.setMarkupId("metroEthernetChildchkLeftId");
         metroEthernetChildchkLeft.add(AttributeModifier.prepend("load", "javascript:addMargin(metroEthernetChildchkLeftId);"));
         metroEthernetChildchkLeft.setEnabled(false);
         commentTechSpeedMetroEthernetListView.add(metroEthernetChildchkLeft);

          add(new IndicatingAjaxButton("submitChoiceCmd")
            {
               private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

               @Override
               protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form< ? > form)
               {
               //// >>>>>>>> updated model value is not coming here <<<<<<
                meSpeedSelectLeft = (ArrayList<String>) metaCommentTechSpeedBean.getMeSpeedSelectLeft();
               });
    }    

    method()
    {
        meSpeedSelectLeft = (ArrayList<String>) metaCommentTechSpeedBean.getMeSpeedSelectLeft();

        leasedLineChildDivLeft.setDefaultModel(new PropertyModel(metaCommentTechSpeedBean, "llSpeedSelectLeft"));
        leasedLineChildDivLeft.setChoices(llSpeedListLeft);
    }
```

i am not able to get checked values [array list of selected checkboxes] in submit method {located in constructor}

Updated :

```
<div wicket:id="metroEthernetChildchkLeft"></div>

  public class MetaCommentTechSpeedChoiceForm extends OForm<MetaCommentTechSpeedBean>
   {

        private CheckBoxMultipleChoice<String> metroEthernetChildchkLeft;

  public MetaCommentTechSpeedChoiceForm(String id)
    {    

          super(id);
                metroEthernetChildchkLeft = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<String>("metroEthernetChildchkLeft");
                metroEthernetChildchkLeft.setMarkupId("metroEthernetChildchkLeftId");
                metroEthernetChildchkLeft.add(AttributeModifier.prepend("load", "javascript:addMargin(metroEthernetChildchkLeftId);"));
                metroEthernetChildchkLeft.setEnabled(false);
                commentTechSpeedMetroEthernetListView.add(metroEthernetChildchkLeft);

                add(new IndicatingAjaxButton("submitChoiceCmd")
                {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form< ? > form)
                    {

                            meSpeedSelectLeft = (ArrayList<String>) metaCommentTechSpeedBean.getMeSpeedSelectLeft(); //// >>>>>>>> updated model value is not coming here <<<<<<
                    });
    }    

    public void formFunction(final MetaCommentCreationBean metaCommentCreationBean, final Component basicInfoContainer, final Component techSpeedSettingsContainer)
    {
            meSpeedSelectLeft = (ArrayList<String>) metaCommentTechSpeedBean.getMeSpeedSelectLeft();
            leasedLineChildDivLeft.setDefaultModel(new PropertyModel(metaCommentTechSpeedBean, "llSpeedSelectLeft"));
            leasedLineChildDivLeft.setChoices(llSpeedListLeft);
    }
```

Comment: Post real code please.

Comment: @DonRoby  real code http://pastebin.com/AFgkPAz0   ;  of java file ; please give little hint what exactly you are looking for

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to debug incomplete code such as you originally posted.  Unfortunately 2000 lines of real code is not much better.  Shorter but still real code exhibiting the problem would be much easier to deal with.  See [SSCCE: How to provide examples for programming questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem occurred due to this line

```
metroEthernetChildchkLeft.setEnabled(false);
```

i disabled the control and enabling it on frontend  using javascript.

Wicket still thinks that the control is disabled and hence not updating the model object.